# Silverlight 4 Out Of Browser: Check for Updates without installing?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

I have created a Silverlight 4 application, that is running out of browser. As you will know, there is a function that is checking if a new version of the app is available and installing it.

But what if I want to only **check** for the update and **not installing** it?

Personally, I do not like applications that silently update themselves, downloading something from the internet. So I'd like to have the following mechanism.
 - when the app starts, it checks if updates are available
 - if so, I show a messagebox to the user, telling her that there is an update and that she can download and installing it via the update-button
 - the user can now decide to update

Unfortunately, there seems to be no option to just checking for updates without actually downloading and installing it. Any ideas, how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can roll your own update detection, by having a small file on your server next to the XAP for your app, that contains the latest version. For example:

```
http://localhost/myawesomeapp.xap
http://localhost/myawesomeapp.xap.ver
```

When you want to check for updates without downloading them, you can always hit the .ver file, check the version listed in it and if newer then the current running app, show the `Update` button to the user.

Note that this approach also would allow you to create more advanced scenarios, like prompting the user to upgrade to a different version of the app (Pro for example) or that they need to upgrade their Silverlight to get the latest.

And if you have multiple apps, you can list all of them in that file and do cross-promotion between your apps.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I have to setup the mechanism myself and make sure that the ver-File is updated, whenever I update my app? And the ver-File is simple text-file with the current Version-Number of my app which the installed app is checked against?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In my proposed solution, you have to create the ver file yourself. It does not have to be a simple text file; since you control both the authoring and the consumption of that file, you're free to choose whatever format makes most sense for you. Meanwhile, you can also automate the task of creating the new file whenever you build a new version of your xap, and publish it to your server together with the updated xap.